# Connection between sum of Graphs and their automorphism groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, automorphism-group

can we say something about the automorphism group of a graph $G$ that has the property: $ G \cong A + B $ , if we know the automorphism groups of $A$ and $B$ respectively. The $+$ is the union $ \cup$ of the $A$ and $B$ with the only addition that $ V(A) \cap V(B)= \emptyset$.

Thank you in advance, any view on this would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming A is not isomorphic to B, the automorphism group is the direct product of the groups of A and B. The direct product can be thought of as the set of elements (a,b) for a in the group for A and b in the group for B. Then (a,c) times (b,d) is (ab,cd), because the automorphism of B does not affect that of A and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you for the answer my actual problem is that i have the situation: $ \xoverline{K_{p,q}}  \cong K_{p} + K_{q} $ where the graphs , are the complete graphs of p and q vertices respectively. Is it still the product?  I mean i know that $ Aut(K_{n})=S_{n}$ ..soo can I conclude to the fact that $Aut(\xoverline{K_{p,q}}=S_{p} \times S{q} $?

Comment: Absolutely! Any pair of permutations of $p,q$ still corresponds to an element of the automorphism group. Don't forget that this is only if $p\neq q$, because otherwise we get things where the points can be mapped to the other subgraph.

Comment: Thank you mate!